# $\tan (x+yi)=\alpha +\beta i \Rightarrow \tan(x-yi)=\alpha-\beta i$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

This example was extracted from S.L. Loney's Plane Trigonometry Volume II.

The problem was to separate real and imaginary parts from the quantity $\tan^{-1}(\alpha + \beta i)$

Then in the book,

Let $\tan^{-1}(\alpha + \beta i)=x+yi$, so that $\tan(x+yi)=\alpha+\beta i$

and$$\tan(x-yi)=\alpha-\beta i,$$
$$\Rightarrow \tan 2x=\tan\{(x+yi)+(x-yi)\}$$and so on...

I want to know how did $\tan(x+yi)=\alpha +\beta i \Rightarrow \tan(x-yi)=\alpha-\beta i$

Comment: $\tan z$ has a Taylor series at $0$ with real coefficients.

Comment: I see.. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use that 
$$
\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})\quad\text{and}\quad\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}).
$$

Then, 
$$\tan(x+iy)=\frac{e^{ix-y}-e^{-ix+y}}{i(e^{ix-y}+e^{-ix+y})}=\frac{e^{-y}e^{ix}-e^ye^{-ix}}{i(e^{-y}e^{ix}+e^ye^{-ix})}$$

Taking conjugates
$$
\overline{\tan(x+iy)}=\frac{e^{-y}e^{-ix}-e^ye^{ix}}{-i(e^{-y}e^{-ix}+e^ye^{ix})}=\frac{e^ye^{ix}-e^{-y}e^{-ix}}{i(e^{-y}e^{-ix}+e^ye^{ix})}.
$$

On the other hand,
$$\tan(x-iy)=\frac{e^{ix+y}-e^{-ix-y}}{i(e^{ix+y}+e^{-ix-y})}=\frac{e^{y}e^{ix}-e^{-y}e^{-ix}}{i(e^ye^{ix}+e^{-y}e^{-ix})}.$$

And we observe that $\overline{\tan(x+iy)}=\tan(x-iy)$, the original statement.

Comment: I don't get this. $\tan x=\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{i(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}$. Substituting $x+yi$ instead of $x$ yields a complex expression

Comment: The i has to be removed

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I didn't quite get your comment, but I fixed the expression because the $i$ should have been in the numerator.  Is that what you were mentioning?

Comment: Yes exactly!....

Comment: Thanks. Btw $\cos x+i\sin x=e^{ix}\Rightarrow \sin x=\dfrac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)$ so $i$ should be in the denom

Answer (score 0):

Okay we know $tan\theta=b/a$ so  $(z)=tan^{-1}(-y/x)$ as its in first quadrant for $z'$ it will be $(z')=tan^{-1}(π+(-y/x))=-tan(y/x)$ so the result  follows .