# If $\tan(\alpha+i\beta)=(x+iy)$ then prove that:

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

If $\tan(\alpha+i\beta)=(x+iy)$ then prove that:

- $x^2+y^2+2x\cot2{\alpha}=1$
- $x^2+y^2-2y\coth2{\beta}=1$

I think that using the concept of logarithm will helpful to solve the problem but I am not able to do so. A detail solution explaining the concept will be helpful.

Thanks in advance !

NB: After going through all the suggestion questions I think all my doubts are cleared with this : **[$\tan (x+yi)=\alpha +\beta i \Rightarrow \tan(x-yi)=\alpha-\beta i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586588/tan-xyi-alpha-beta-i-rightarrow-tanx-yi-alpha-beta-i?rq=1)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $$\tan(2\alpha)=\tan\{\alpha+i\beta+(\alpha-i\beta)\}=?$$

and $$\tan(2i\beta)=\tan\{\alpha+i\beta-(\alpha-i\beta)\}=?$$

Now $\tan(2i\beta)=i\tanh(2\beta)$

Comment: I am not able to see why consider $\tan(2\alpha)$ and $\tan(2i\beta)$

Comment: @Ayush, As $$\cot2\alpha=\dfrac1{\tan2\alpha}$$  and $$\tan(2i\beta)=\dfrac{e^{-2\beta}-e^{2\beta}}{i(e^{2\beta}+e^{-2\beta})}=-\dfrac{\sinh(2\beta)}{i\cosh(2\beta)}=i\tanh(2\beta)$$

Comment: okay the confusions are cleared after this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586588/tan-xyi-alpha-beta-i-rightarrow-tanx-yi-alpha-beta-i?rq=1